# Avoid switch in favor of polymorphism without class

Tags: swift

I'm looking for a way to either make a function accept a specific switch case, or any other way to achieve what I want, which is something like this:

```
protocol CommonType {}
struct A: CommonType {}
struct B: CommonType {}

func f(_ a: A) {
    print("A")
}
func f(_ b: B) {
    print("B")
}

let x: CommonType = A()
f(x) // expect to print "A"
```

So basically I need a way to have `f` conditionally called based on the type of my struct.

Obviously I can do something like this:

```
switch x {
case let y as A:
    f(y)
case let y as B:
    f(y)
default: ()
}
```

but that's exactly what I wanna avoid (i.e., I'm looking for a more elegant way).

Answer (score 3):

Polymorphism works with methods of class, struct, and enum. Polymorphism with standalone functions doesn't make sense. What you've defined is overloaded functions.

How about adding the function to your protocol definition?  That way, the compiler will ensure that every `class`, `struct`, or `enum` that implements `CommonType` will implement `func f()`:

```
protocol CommonType {
    func f()
}
struct A: CommonType {
    func f() {
        print("A")
    }
}
struct B: CommonType {
    func f() {
        print("B")
    }
}

let x: CommonType = A()
x.f() // prints "A"
```

---

> Nope, I need it as a function, because I'll use those in multiple
>   places that are totally unrelated, so my protocol would be bloated.
>   Plus, I'm more into FP than OO.

I don't understand the concern for a bloated protocol.  By adding the function to the protocol definition, you ensure that it will be properly implemented by every struct that implements the protocol.  The compiler will enforce it.  You could write a wrapper if you insist on a function:

```
func f(_ x: CommonType) {
    x.f()
}

f(x)  // prints "A"
```

Comment: Nope, I need it as a function, because I'll use those in multiple places that are totally unrelated, so my protocol would be bloated. Plus, I'm more into FP than OO.

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz "Plus, I'm more into FP than OO" is meaningless. You're asking for polymorphism, so use polymorphism.

Comment: polymorphism in a function, not a method.

Comment: Polymorphism works with methods of class, struct, and enum.  Polymorphism with standalone functions doesn't make sense.  What you've defined is overloaded functions.

Comment: Ok, maybe I've used the wrong term, so I'm looking for a way to overload the function =)

Comment: Unfortunately, since Swift is statically typed, the types of the variables must be known at compile time, so in order to call the overloaded functions you have to establish the type like you've done with your switch statement.

Comment: It wasn't the answer I was looking for =/, but I'll vote you up for the patience to try helping me out =).